# Code First reverse engineering differential poco and configuration updates

Tags: ef-code-first, reverse-engineering

Does anyone know a possibility to reverse engineer only the differences between my actual code first pocos / fluent api configuration and the database structure?
When I use ef power tools to reverse engineer, it's all overwritten.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a code first migration it will describe the differences. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: I meant reverse engineering from database to pocos, dbcontext. All of the pocos and the dbcontext generated are overridden.

Comment: With the EF Tools for VS 2013 you can reverse engineer your existing database objects (or just a subset of them) into a separate folder and then compare them to your existing POCOs. I do this all the time when migrating larger existing databases since I like to bring them in little by little and do some customizations..